# How can I send a 301 Permanent Redirect with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, http, redirect, http-status-code-301, permanent

I need to permanent redirect some pages, and redirect the user to the new URL as well.

This code only sets the correct headers. The user are not redirected.

```
public static void PermanentRedirect(this HttpResponse response, string newUrl)
{
  response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
  response.StatusCode = 301;
  response.AddHeader("Location", newUrl);
}
```

If I put:

```
Response.Redirect(newUrl);
```

at the end, a 302 Temporary Redirect is performed.

How can I 301 redirect the user?

> **Related Questions:**
>
> [How do I programatically 301 redirect in an asp page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868851/how-do-i-programatically-301-redirect-in-an-asp-page)

Comment: I just wrote a blog post on that: http://www.ko-sw.com/Blog/post/Permanent-Redirect-Using-ASPNET.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Response.Flush and Response.End. Redirect says to end the request by sending a 302.

Answer (score 2):

Note in ASP.NET 4.0 this is now built-in so you can use the [RedirectPermanent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.redirectpermanent.aspx) method. e.g.

```
RedirectPermanent("/newpath/foroldcontent.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

or maybe try ISAPI? it mimicks mod_rewrite and other .htaccess functionality on IIS.