# How to force 301 Redirect to some old pages in asp.net while having url rewrite for these pages

Tags: asp.net, redirect, http-status-code-301

In our application we do url rewrite for all the pages. For example you have . Recently we changed all the urls to be /adults/about/ or /kids/about/ ... Now all the previous urls like "/about/" will give 404. Is there a way to add 301 redirect and force all the pages like "/about/" to go to "/adults/about/". I found a way but I am not sure it is a good one or it will help in SEO. What I did is added a url rewrite for the "/about/" like the "/adults/about/" and then in the page_Load checked if there is no "adults" or "kids" in the url then redirect to "/adults/about/". The adults and kids are not folders. They just help in differentiating the nav menu.

Sorry if the title is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the URL in `Application_BeginRequest` in your global.asax file. If the `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` matches an old page, do an 301 redirect to the corresponding new page.

You can check this through Regular Expressions for example.

Here is explained [how to do a proper 301 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083337/how-can-i-send-a-301-permanent-redirect-with-asp-net?rq=1).

Comment: I wasnt aware of the Application_BeginRequest. I think I should reread about the page cycle. Thank you