# How to 301 redirect default.asp to root domain (/)?

Tags: redirect, asp-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I programatically 301 redirect in an asp page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868851/how-do-i-programatically-301-redirect-in-an-asp-page)

Please share various ways.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a bummer this was marked as an exact duplicate.  This question is specific to issuing a 301 from /default.asp in ASP Classic to the domain root.  This is a SPECIFIC problem that is not solved with the referenced duplicate question above.  This should be re-opened.

Comment: Hey Harvey reopen this question.  This is not an exact duplicate as you claim.  Maybe you should take more time before you condescend.