# What did Microsoft do wrong that returns a 302 redirect status versus a 301 status?

Tags: redirect, asp-classic

First let me say... I AM NOT A PROGRAMMER.  I can't even SPELL "ASP".  However I need help with the following ASP Coding problem.  Microsoft tech support wrote the code (below) for me and I am using on my website now.  However we ran into a problem where the code seems to be returning a 302 status versus a 301 status.  This can be confirmed here:  :  http://www.howto301redirect.com/301-redirect-checker/

### Here's the code...

```
<%
Dim serverName 
serverName = Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")

    Dim canRedirect 
canRedirect = "False"


Dim hostNameArray(14) 'Array of host name

hostNameArray(0) = "bananapages.net"
hostNameArray(1) = "www.bananapages.net"
hostNameArray(2) = "6379100.com"
hostNameArray(3) = "www.6379100.com"
hostNameArray(4) = "caribbeanexhibits.com"
hostNameArray(5) = "www.caribbeanexhibits.com"
hostNameArray(6) = "caribbeanspecialevents.com"
hostNameArray(7) = "www.caribbeanspecialevents.com"
hostNameArray(8) = "caribeexpo.com"
hostNameArray(9) = "www.caribeexpo.com"
hostNameArray(10) = "daleallenenterprises.com"
hostNameArray(11) = "www.daleallenenterprises.com"
hostNameArray(12) = "daleallen.com"
hostNameArray(13) = "rrcpapsc.com"
hostNameArray(14) = "www.rrcpapsc.com"

For Each item In hostNameArray
    If serverName = item  Then
        serverName = "www.daleallen.com"
        canRedirect = "True"
        Exit For
    End If
Next


If canRedirect = "True" Then

    Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"

    If Request.QueryString <> "" Then
      Response.Redirect "http://" & serverName & Request.ServerVariables        ("HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL")      & "?" & Request.QueryString
    Else
      Response.Redirect "http://" & serverName & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL")
    End If 
End If 
%>
```

---

what did Microsoft do wrong that brings back a 302 status?
We are using ASP scripting

Dale Allen

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I programatically 301 redirect in an asp page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868851/how-do-i-programatically-301-redirect-in-an-asp-page)

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be here:

```
If Request.QueryString <> "" Then
  Response.AddHeader "Location", "http://" & serverName & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL") & "?" & Request.QueryString  

Else
  Response.AddHeader "Location", "http://" & serverName & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL") 
End If
```

End If 
%>